# Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory when using QjackCtl

Tags: jack

When I try to start a jack server I get [these error messages](http://pastebin.com/ntRqWdEg) and also a window pops up saying:

```
Could not connect to JACK server as client.
                             - Overall operation failed.
                             - Unable to connect to server.
                             Please check the messages window for more info.
```

Any idea on how to fix this? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
This is my `jackd --version` output:

```
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2014 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
jackdmp version 1.9.10 tmpdir /dev/shm protocol 8
```

Comment: I used to have issues with this I think going to settings and set "interface" as the input device, Leave the box "input" as default and set "output" to the output device and restart qjackctl, it seems strange but it worked for me.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didnt work it still says 'Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel'

Comment: did you solve your problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

how do you start jack ?

some suggestions:

```
run jack as user, not as root 
try using qjackctl 

adjust 
/etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf 
if required (for realtime audio only !!)


disable autospawn in /etc/pulse/client.conf
and stop pulseaudio 
sudo pulseaudio --kill
```

if you get jack running, later you can

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-jack
```

and re-enable pulseaudio

Answer (score 0):

For me, the messages about

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

have been entirely misleading.
My problem was similar in that it also printed this when starting jack failed,
but it also printed this when it worked! (indicating it's maybe trying to find some part of it's system that's still up from previous runs or whatever).
It was also similar because somewhere in the middle of the error message, it complained about the 'audio card':

```
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
Jack: JackDriver::Close
```

and subsequently about the driver, like in your pastebin, except your error message is slightly different, because I set it to verbose and your ALSA thing is reporting a slightly different problem.
I hope my solution of, in QjackCtl, fiddling with the "interface" setting works. I read somewhere else that one of the options is my real audio card, and for me, selecting

```
hw:Generic_1,0
```

worked.
Due to rummaging through SO in search of an answer to this question, I have also fiddled with the "Real-Time" checkbox, which does not prevent it from working and the corresponding

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p high jackd2
```

setting, which i set to "yes", as well as done the recommended setup in https://jackaudio.org/faq/linux_rt_config.html, though that does not seem to be your problem as your jack is successfully saying, like mine,

```
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
```

Hope you have an 'Audio Card' problem as well! SuperCollider is now successfully connecting and making noises. It's actually kind of weird that a "configuration" issue, which the 'Messages' window of QjackCtl shows is actually just some words on the command line, can be a problem for SuperCollider, which doesn't ask me these questions and starts jack itself, but I guess jack remembers the settings from QjackCtl somehow.